# Writing ServerValue Timestamp is calculated twice by the sever?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the ServerValue Timestamp in my project and I would like to create relation by using the timestamp as a key.

**When the "setValue" is executed the timestamp is calculated twice and I have to observe the ".childAdded" and the ".childChanged" to obtain the correct timestamp value. (ಠ_ಠ)** 
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRServerValue)

Used frameworks:
Firebase (3.15.0),
FirebaseAnalytics (3.7.0),
FirebaseAuth (3.1.1),
FirebaseCore (3.5.2),
FirebaseDatabase (3.1.2),
FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.9)

Example snippet code in Swift:

```
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("test").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        if let value = snapshot.value as? Int {
            print("Child added, timestamp value: \(value) ")
        }
    })

    ref.child("test").observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in

        if let value = snapshot.value as? Int {
            print("Child change, timestamp value: \(value) ")
        }
    })

    ref.child("test").setValue(["one" : FIRServerValue.timestamp()]) { error, ref in
        print("New child inserted.")
    }
```

Console output:

- Child added, timestamp value: 1490950004556
- Child change, timestamp value: 1490950005970
- New child inserted.

[image: Imgur]

If the setValue is executed by an other user (other connected client) then only the "childAdded" event is invoking which is nice :)

Referring to this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/30244373/4427983 it seems that the timestamp is calculated locally first by the firebase framework. Can I disable somehow this feature and force the framework to calculate the timestamp value only at sever side?