# Swift 4: Firebase Timestamp

Tags: swift, firebase

How should i compare Firebase Timestamp with local device time.

```
let serverTIme = FIRServerValue.timestamp()
let localtime = Date()
let dbRef = FirebaseServerReference()
```

here is full code https://pastebin.com/4drtSZA6

**Edit:** 
When i set timestamp in Firebase RealtimeDatabase using `FIRServerValue.timestamp` it suppose to save timestamp of Server not the my device time. 
In my case, it looks like it is depending on my device time. i want to check that if there is a ‘Time Difference’ in server time & my device time.

So i think that this question might not possible duplicate of [Trying to convert Firebase timestamp to NSDate in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243060/trying-to-convert-firebase-timestamp-to-nsdate-in-swift).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to convert Firebase timestamp to NSDate in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243060/trying-to-convert-firebase-timestamp-to-nsdate-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert Firebase timestamp to `NSDate` and then compare `Date()` later on. Here is a similar question and a possible solution: 
[Trying to convert Firebase timestamp to NSDate in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243060/trying-to-convert-firebase-timestamp-to-nsdate-in-swift)

Comment: when you change your device time then the timestamp will be same on firebase. it will be useless when device time is not accurate/true.