# Pagination not working propperly swift 4 Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database, pagination, swift4

Hey i've got a litle app that users can upload posts and and then all posts are saved in a global view inside a tableview with the height of the rows at 500 so that the images are big enough but when there is only 4 posts then the images starts to freak out and post 1 and post 4 is starting to change images with each other untill the cell is propperly loaded but i thought maybe pagination would help but i got no luck so for this is what i have tryed for now:

```
var startKey: String!
func handlePagination()
{
    /*
     querying the first 3 posts in the database
     if the start key is equal to nil tis part of the code will be executed and set the last key id to the start key to fetch the following posts

     */
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "timeorder")

    if startKey == nil {
        ref.queryLimited(toLast: 3).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else {return}

            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]
                {
                    guard let dictionary = child.value as? [String:Any] else {return}
                    self.posts.insert(dictionary as NSDictionary , at: 0)
                }
                self.startKey = children.key
                print("firstKey is :\(self.startKey)")
                self.postsTableView.reloadData()
            }

        })
    }

    else{
        ref.queryStarting(atValue:self.startKey).queryLimited(toLast: 3).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("1")
            guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return}
            print("2")
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]
                {
                    if child.key != self.startKey{
                        guard let dictionary = child.value as? [String:Any] else {return}
                        self.posts.insert(dictionary as NSDictionary , at: self.posts.count)
                        print("3")
                    }
                }
                self.startKey = children.key
                print("secondKEy is :\(self.startKey)")
                self.postsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        })

    }// end of else of start key
}
/*
 using end of scroll to handle pagination if the offset is less than or equal to 150 from the current item position... calculating distance using maxoffset and the currentoffset
 */

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maxOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
    if maxOffset - currentOffset <= 150{
        print("More Posts Maybe?")
        self.handlePagination()

    }
}
```

this code runs perfectly and is actually getting the last post id and is fetching more posts from that last id but the code stops automaticlly at `print("1")` 
i'm new to this Guard statements so i tryed removing it and i got to `print("2")` and then the code doesnt work ferther i'm not exactly sure what is going on here but i know i'm not far from the solution (i hope), Any help is Greatly appreciated. thanks for your time.

Comment: This is not an issue with pagination. It's an issue that arises because tableview cells are reused. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35958896/7245977 and 
 https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: okey thans i will take a lok at this @DoesData

Comment: i fixed this real easy actually i just added cell.postsImage.image = nil before the image is download so instead of it showing an other post it is white for maybe 0.5 seconds then the post is show i could i also use an other image instead of nil, but thanks for the help any ways :) @DoesData

Comment: You should clear the image out in prepareForReuse() https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse