# How to parse Firestore FieldValue to Date in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing a document within a collection in a Cloud Firestore database. In this document, I want a reference to when the document was stored so I am using Firestore's [FieldValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FieldValue) object which has a `serverTimeStamp()` function.

I am unable to parse this FieldValue object on the client as either a `Date/NSDate` or `String`. I have spent some time reading the Firestore iOS documentation and cannot find any leads on this.

There is no issue getting the `FieldValue` from the database to the client, however, I am unable to cast/convert the timeStamp of type `FieldValue` to anything.

Attempts to convert to string and date:

`let timeStampString : String = message.timeStamp`

`let timeStampDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: message.timeStamp)`

- Cannot assign value of type `FieldValue` to type `String`
- Cannot convert value of type `FieldValue` to expected argument type `TimeInterval` (aka `Double`)

Edit: After reviewing Doug Stevenson's answer, the best way to handle this is by casting your timeStamp value to a TimeStamp (not FieldValue) when reading the info on the client.

```
let timeStamp = document["yourTimeStampKey"] as! TimeStamp
```

rather than

```
let timeStamp = document["yourTimeStampKey"] as! FieldValue
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no parsing needed.  Firestore timestamp fields are of type [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp), which you should use directly.  It represents a point in time with nanosecond precision.

Code:

```
let timeStamp = document["yourTimeStampKey"] as! TimeStamp
```

rather than

```
let timeStamp = document["yourTimeStampKey"] as! FieldValue
```

Comment: I don't understand. When the value is retrieved on the client, I am storing the timestamp as a FieldValue by doing something like document["timeStamp"] as? FieldValue. How do you get from FieldValue to TimeStamp? Are you suggesting casting document["timeStamp"] as a TimeStamp and not as a FieldValue?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting anything of type FieldValue from a query.  There are only two FieldValue type values, and they are used when you write data.  You can't put a serverTimestamp() sentinel into a document, then get it right back out as a Timestamp.  The timestamp gets calculated on the server when the document write occurs.

Comment: I keep getting null value when trying to retrieve timestamp from firestore any ideas why?

Comment: Swift 5  `TimeStamp` -> `Timestamp`

Comment: Please check Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56662889/2781088