# Convert Firebase Firestore Timestamp to Date (Swift)?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a date saved in a Firestore field as a timestamp that I want to convert to a Date in Swift:

`June 19,2018 at 7:20:21 PM UTC-4`

I tried the following but I get an error:

`let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: postTimestamp as! TimeInterval)`

Error:

`Could not cast value of type 'FIRTimestamp' (0x104fa8b98) to 'NSNumber'`

The reason why I want to convert to Date is so that I can use this Date extension to mimic timestamps you see on Instagram posts:

```
extension Date {
    func timeAgoDisplay() -> String {
        let secondsAgo = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince(self))

        let minute = 60
        let hour = 60 * minute
        let day = 24 * hour
        let week = 7 * day

        if secondsAgo < minute {
            return "\(secondsAgo) seconds ago"
        } else if secondsAgo < hour {
            return "\(secondsAgo / minute) minutes ago"
        } else if secondsAgo < day {
            return "\(secondsAgo / hour) hours ago"
        } else if secondsAgo < week {
            return "\(secondsAgo / day) days ago"
        }

        return "\(secondsAgo / week) weeks ago"
    }
}
```

Comment: The date is a **timestamp**, not an interval. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50890744

Comment: FYI the official Firebase pod, FirebaseFirestoreSwift now allows encoding/decoding conversion of Date to FIRTimestamp and vice versa

Comment: Please check answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56662889/2781088

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Either do:

```
let date = postTimestamp.dateValue()
```

or you could do:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: postTimestamp.seconds)
```

See the [Timestamp reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp).

Comment: Thank you that's a nice method