# Why dosen't timeIntervalSince1970 show up in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, timestamp

I want to convert the timestamp I have saved to Firebase to real time time. I have seen some codes here, and watched some youtube videos, but for some odd reason I can't get the `timeIntervalSince1970` function up?

The only available function I can call is `NSTimeIntervalSince1970`. Why is this?

Comment: Please show your code with enough context. And where is _codes here_ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Firebase Firestore Timestamp to Date (Swift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116381/convert-firebase-firestore-timestamp-to-date-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timeIntervalSince1970` is a property of Date.  A Firestore [Timestamp](http://timeIntervalSince1970) object is not a Date - it is its own type.  If you want to convert it to a Date, you can call its [dateValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp#datevalue) method.  This will give you a Date, and you can use `timeIntervalSince1970` on that.

Or, even better, you can use the [seconds](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp#seconds) property on the Timestamp directly and skip Date altogether.

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to use `Date().timeIntervalSince1970`