# Get readable date from firebase timestamp, which is saved as number

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here's the problem I have: 
Some smart guy saved timestamps in our database as strings. So dates for created documents look like this: 1569260406765

Here's my code:

```swift
tasksRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let docs = querySnapshot?.documents {
        for docSnapshot in docs {
            print("Snapshot:" ,docSnapshot.data())
            let dateCreated = docSnapshot.get("dateCreated")
            let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: dateCreated as! TimeInterval)

            print("dateCreated:", date)
            self.recentOrderNowsFirst.text = "\(String(describing: dateCreated))"

        }
    }
}
```

which gets me this error:

Could not cast value of type 'FIRTimestamp' (0x101df5660) to 'NSNumber'

How can I fix this? 
Appreciate any help.

Comment: It looks to me like the smart guy actually use a timestamp type field for dateCreated, not a string.  That's what FIRTimestamp refers to.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Firebase Firestore Timestamp to Date (Swift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116381/convert-firebase-firestore-timestamp-to-date-swift)

Comment: yes it seems like he used a FIRTimestamp, but then in the database he saved it as a number or string and I have no idea how to convert it to a readable format?