# Converting timestamp to a different timezone (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, date, timezone

**What I want to do:**
Take the timestamp from my database and convert it to the timezone of the user.

**My code:**

```
let tryItNow = "\(model.timestampName)"
        
let format = DateFormatter()       
let date = format.date(from: tryItNow)       
format.timeZone = .current       
format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"       
let dateString = format.string(from: date!)   //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
print(dateString)
```

**The problem:** I guess Xcode tells me, that `date` is empty, which can't really be true. I get the timestamp from a struct and this whole thing is in a function, that's why its called `model.timestampName`.

**What I tried:** Searching on the internet, here on stack overflow (most tutorials are 3 years old and I did not find anything for my specific case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify a `format.dateFormat` **before** converting your date:

```
let format = DateFormatter()      
format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" // <- format of model.timestampName
let date = format.date(from: tryItNow)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, and yes this did solve one problem, but now I have another one. ```Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value```at the datestring

Comment: I looked up how my timestamp (tryItNow) looks and Xcode tells me ```<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1593194260 nanoseconds=311962000>```. Do I have to change the code bcs of that?

Comment: @JanSwoboda Please see [Convert Firebase Firestore Timestamp to Date (Swift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116381/convert-firebase-firestore-timestamp-to-date-swift)