# How to write the down casting from Timestamp to Date in Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

```
struct User: Codable,Identifiable,Hashable{
   var @DocumentID var id: String?
   var name: String
   var birthDay: Timestamp?
}



struct Profile: View {
   @Binding var user: User
   @State var birthDay: Date
   init(){
     self._birthDay = State(initialValue:  _user.wrappedValue.birthDay as! Timestamp 
   }
}
```

I don't know how to  write the down casting from Firestore's Timestamp to Date.
I got the error `Cannot convert value of type 'Timestamp' to expected argument type 'Date'` in `self._birthDay = State(initialValue:  _user.wrappedValue.birthDay as! Timestamp` .
If `_user.wrappedValue.birthDay` is nil, I want to set the current date.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116381/convert-firebase-firestore-timestamp-to-date-swift)
But this is possible for nil. I want to set the current date if it is nil.
And User's birthday is optional. So I want to set jest Date type.

I think I can write this

```
let timestamp = _user.wrappedValue.birthDay as! Timestamp 
let date = timestamp.dateValue()
```

But I don't know if the timestamp is nil how to set current date.

I tried writing the down casting. But I can't get success.
Especially I don't know how to write that in 1 statement.

Comment: You can't downcast. You need to use the Timestamp `dateValue()` function, which creates a `Date` from a `Timestamp`.

Comment: I know I can write this `let timestamp = _user.wrappedValue.birthDay as! Timestamp let date = timestamp.dateValue()` But  I don't know how to write this context like that.

Comment: `let date = (_user.wrappedValue.birthDay as? Timestamp ?? TimeStamp(date: Date())).dateValue()` should work

Comment: Not working.  Though I already imported `Firebase` and `FirebaseFirestore` , I got the error `Cannot find 'TimeStamp' in scope` at `TimeStamp(date: Date()))`

Comment: Oh, change "Time**S**tamp" to "Timestamp". (Switch the "S" to lower case.)

Comment: Case matters in Swift types (as in most C-like languages.) My fingers tend to type camel case automatically, so I capitalized the "S" by mistake.

Comment: I changed `TimeStamp` to `Timestamp`. But I got another error `Value of type 'State<Timestamp>' has no member 'dateValue'` in dateValue() .

Comment: That’s a SwiftUI issue. I don’t really know SwiftUI