# How can I convert a Firebase timestamp placeholder into a timestamp in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase

I used the following line to add a timestamp to a document in Firebase `"createdAT": Firebase.ServerValue.timestamp()`  When I grab the document from Firebase and run the line of code `print(document["createdAT"])` , I receive this in the console:

```
{".sv" = timestamp;}
```

Is there a way to convert that to an actual timestamp in Swift?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44261841/5078779) seems closely related to your issue.

Comment: @Daniel. Unfortunately, I have tried all of the solutions on that page and cannot obtain a timestamp.